# WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.0 - Error message not shown in IS Management Console while creating already existing User

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.0.
when creating users through Identity Server Management console, If user is already exists we are getting below error in logs and User is not getting added:
`ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient} - UserAlreadyExisting:Username already exists in the system. Please pick another username. org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminUserAdminException: UserAdminUserAdminException`

**However error message is not shown in IS management console**

Answer (score 1):

What is the WUM version of the WSO2IS-5.10 you are using? To find the WUM version of your WSO2IS use the WUM (WSO2 Update Manager)
 [[https://www.chakray.com/how-install-wso2-update-manager-wum-tool-apply-wso2-patches/]](https://www.chakray.com/how-install-wso2-update-manager-wum-tool-apply-wso2-patches/) 
I tried adding two same users named users in WSO2IS-5.10 but it seems to give me the error message in the admin console. check this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igXPm.png),

To check that there are any other issues is happening and blocking the display of error messages, can enable the debug mode in ***Log4J.properties*** file in ***< IS-HOME >/repository/conf*** folder. And check the link below to see how to set up Log4j.properties file.
 [[https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/enable-logging-in-wso2-identity-server-with-log4j2-4b2ef1374656]](https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/enable-logging-in-wso2-identity-server-with-log4j2-4b2ef1374656)